# Why is $('[tabindex="1"]').focus(); focusing on tabindex="2"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On pressing tab when the submit button is focused, focus should return to `tabindex="1"`.  Here's the HTML:

```
<input tabindex="1" id="tabindex1" value="tabindex='1'" autofocus>
<input tabindex="2" id="tabindex2" value="tabindex='2'">
<input tabindex="3" id="tabindex3" value="tabindex='3'">
<input tabindex="4" id="submit_button" type="submit">
```

And here's the JQuery:

```
$("input").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9 && $(":focus").attr("id") == "submit_button") {
        $('[tabindex="1"]').focus(); // Focuses on tabindex="2"!!!
        // $('#tabindex1').focus(); // Does the same thing
    }
});
```

And [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/s0Luwpu2/).  For the life of me, I can't figure out why it's going to `tabindex="2"` instead of `tabindex="1"`, and it's even doing that when I use the `id` attribute instead of `tabindex`.  How do I get it to go to `tabindex="1"`?

**Update**: The solutions below from both [soktinpk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3371119/soktinpk) and [hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs) did the trick. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/q897443n/) showing it working with `return false;` and here's a fiddle showing it working with `e.preventDefault();`. Follow-up question: is one of these two solutions preferable to the other?

Comment: Add `return false` to the `if` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return false` to the end of the `if` statement:

```js
$("input").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9 && $(":focus").attr("id") == "submit_button") {
        $('[tabindex="1"]').focus(); // Focuses on tabindex="2"!!!
        // $('#tabindex1').focus(); // Does the same thing
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<input tabindex="1" id="tabindex1" value="tabindex='1'" autofocus>
<input tabindex="2" id="tabindex2" value="tabindex='2'">
<input tabindex="3" id="tabindex3" value="tabindex='3'">
<input tabindex="4" id="submit_button" type="submit">
```

The problem is, it focuses on the first input and then the browser performs the default action which is to focus on the *next* input. So, ultimately, it focuses on the second input.

Returning false ensures that the browser doesn't take the default behavior.

Comment: Alternatively, `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not preventing the default action, and the default action of tab is to move to the next tabindex. So your callback focuses tabindex 1, and then the default behavior of the tab key focuses tabindex 2.